# What number the letter O represents in this cryptarithm?

Tags: arithmetic, cryptarithm

I found a question and I do not know how to do it. The goes as:
If letters all represent digits, what is the value of O in:

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
&&&&O&N&E\\
+&&&F&O&U&R\\
\hline
&&&F&I&V&E\\
\end{array}$$

and

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
&&&&O&N&E\\
x&&&&&&4\\
\hline
&&&F&O&U&R\\
\end{array}$$

**What I know**

I have figured out that the R is a zero and E is a 5. But then I do not know how to go on. I went with N being 3 in the second algorithm and found that I got stuck. I tried some more but that didn't work either.

Just Reference: The 4 can be repeated, no other number can be repeated unless it is the same number. Can I have some help, please?

Comment: If $E=1$, then $ONE\times 4=ON1\times 4=\cdots 4=FOUR$. So $R$ cannot be $0$, hence $E$ is not $1$.

Comment: $$ONE+4(ONE)=FIVE$$

hence $E=0$ or $5$ because $FIVE$ is divisble by $5$

Comment: @DietrichBurde then what is R?

Comment: **If** $E=1$ then $R$ cannot be zero. So, consequently if you think that $R=0$, then $E\neq 1$. And indeed, $E=0$ and not $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From "ONE+FOUR=FIVE" one gets $R=0$, thus "ON+FOU=FIV", thus "ON+OU=IV", thus $1\leqslant O\leqslant4$.
2. From "4·ONE=FOU0" you get that $E\equiv 0 \pmod 5$.
3. Assuming different letters represent different figures, $E=5$ because 0 is already occupied by $R$.
4. 4·ON5=FOU0", thus $U$ is even, $F=1$ and

   - $O\neq1$ because otherwise "4·ON5" would by smaller than 1000.
   - $O \neq 4$ because otherwise $O\geqslant6$.
   - $O \neq 2$ because otherwise "12xy / 4 = 3wz" and hence $O=3$.

Hence $O=3$